# Since characters from -128 to -1 are same as from +128 to +255, then what is the point of using unsigned char?

Tags: c, char, unsigned-char

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    char a=-128;
    while(a<=-1)
    {
        printf("%c\n",a);
        a++;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**The output of the above code is same as the output of the code below**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char a=+128;
    while(a<=+254)
    {
        printf("%c\n",a);
        a++;
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Then why we use `unsigned char` and `signed char`?

Comment: One argument: signed overflow is UB.

Comment: `-128` and `+128` are different values, however `printf("%c"` performs a conversion that prints the same character for both cases.

Comment: @SouravGhosh overflow of `char` cannot happen (except on `sizeof(int)==1` machines) because `char` is promoted to `int` before any arithmetic.  The `int` arithmetic may overflow, but then that is also a problem for `unsigned char` because the latter also promotes to `int`.

Comment: @M.M That is in case of `%c` argument, I was talking in general.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I am talking in general, and not about `%c`

Comment: What you are missing is the importance of the `signed` aspect of `char`. That provides the range of `-128 - 127` but has more subtle implications related to *sign-extention* during bitwise operations, etc.. On the other hand, `unsigned char` has a range of `0-255` and does not undergo sign extension related to its leftmost bit.

Comment: `char` sign is not defined.

Comment: `-128 to 0` is 129 numbers.  `+128 to +255` is 128 numbers.  Obvious problem with title: "characters from -128 to 0 are same as from +128 to +255".  Fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With printing characters - no difference:

The function `printf()` uses `"%c"` and takes the `int` argument and converts it to `unsigned char` and *then* prints it.

```
char a;
printf("%c\n",a);  // a is converted to int, then passed to printf()
unsigned char ua;
printf("%c\n",ua); // ua is converted to int, then passed to printf()
```

With printing values (numbers) - difference when system uses a `char` that is  *signed*:

```
char a = -1;
printf("%d\n",a);     // --> -1
unsigned char ua = -1;
printf("%d\n",ua);    // --> 255  (Assume 8-bit unsigned char)
```

Note: Rare machines will have `int` the same size as `char` and other concerns apply.

**So if code uses `a` as a number rather than a character, the printing differences are significant.**

Answer (score 3):

K & R, chapter and verse, p. 43 and 44:

> There is one subtle point about the conversion of characters to
>   integers. The language does not specify whether variables of type char
>   are signed or unsigned quantities. When a char is converted to an int,
>   can it ever produce a negative integer? The answer varies from machine
>   to machine, reflecting differences in architecture. On some machines,
>   a char whose leftmost bit is 1 will be converted to a negative integer
>   ("sign extension"). On others, a char is promoted to an int by adding
>   zeros at the left end, and thus is always positive. [...] Arbitrary
>   bit patterns stored in character variables may appear to be negative
>   on some machines, yet positive on others. For portability, specify
>   signed or unsigned if non-character data is to be stored in char
>   variables.

Answer (score 2):

Because `unsigned char` is used for one byte integer in `C89`.

Note there are three distinct `char` related types in `C89`: `char`, `signed char`, `unsigned char`.

For character type, `char` is used.

`unsigned char` and `signed char` are used for one byte integers like `short` is used for two byte integers. You should not really use `signed char` or `unsigned char` for characters. Neither should you rely on the order of those values.

Answer (score 2):

The bit representation of a number is what the computer stores, but it doesn't mean anything without someone (or something) imposing a pattern onto it.

The difference between the `unsigned char` and `signed char` patterns is how we interpret the set bits.  In one case we decide that zero is the smallest number and we can add bits until we get to `0xFF` or binary `11111111`.  In the other case we decide that `0x80` is the smallest number and we can add bits until we get to `0x7F`.

The reason we have the funny way of representing signed numbers (the latter pattern) is because it places zero `0x00` roughly in the middle of the sequence, and because `0xFF` (which is -1, right before zero) plus `0x01` (which is 1, right after zero) add together to carry until all the bits carry off the high end leaving 0x00 `(-1 + 1 = 0)`.  Likewise `-5 + 5 = 0` by the same mechanisim.

For fun, there are a lot of bit patterns that mean different things.  For example `0x2a` might be what we call a "number" or it might be a `*` character.  It depends on the context we choose to impose on the bit patterns.

Comment: The biggest and best reason is because one type makes the code easier to understand in one context.  For example, I could use `signed char` to store number of children a family might have, but that would be very confusing and permit negative children.  Better to use a `unsigned char`, permitting a few more children (254 max) and completely making my code clear that the number is not negative.  Finally, your `printf` implicitly casts to a character, if you want the decimal representation it is `printf("%d", ...)` which will show the expected difference in values

Answer (score 0):

Different types are created to tell the compiler how to "understand" the bit representation of one or more bytes. For example, say I have a byte which contains `0xFF`. If it's interpreted as a `signed char`, it's -1; if it's interpreted as a `unsigned char`, it's 255.

In your case, `a`, no matter whether signed or unsigned, is integral promoted to `int`, and passed to `printf()`, which later implicitly convert it to `unsigned char` before printing it out as a character.

But let's consider another case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char a = -1;
    unsigned char b;
    memmove(&b, &a, 1);
    printf("%d %u", a, b);
}
```

It's practically acceptable to simply write `printf("%d %u", a, a);`. `memmove()` is used just to avoid undefined behaviour.

It's output on my machine is:

```
-1 4294967295
```

Also, think about this ridiculous question:

> Suppose `sizeof (int) == 4`, since arrays of characters `(unsigned
>   char[]){UCHAR_MIN, UCHAR_MIN, UCHAR_MIN, UCHAR_MIN}` to `(unsigned
>   char[]){UCHAR_MAX, UCHAR_MAX, UCHAR_MAX, UCHAR_MAX}` are same as
>   `unsigned int`s from `UINT_MIN` to `UINT_MAX`, then what is the point
>   of using `unsigned int`?